# Puzzled student, not being able to figure out why my migrations won't work

Tags: laravel, constraints, laravel-migrations, mysql-error-1068

I'm running into problems with Laravel migrations and creating database tables. Specifically with the constraints.
When I execute the command `php artisan:migrate fresh` I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `users` add primary key (id))`

So I'm building a website with 3 database tables:

- Users,
- Questions
- Comments

**Questions** has a column called `user_id` and should be bound to `id` in the table **Users**.

**Comments** also has a `user_id` table, and should also be bound to `id` in **Users**.

In addition, it also has a `question_id` column, which should be connected to `id` in the **Question** table.

Here are the Laravel migrations:

Users:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->primary();
            $table->text('name');
            $table->enum('role', ['admin', 'user'])->default('user');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comments:

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_id');
            $table->text('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
 Schema::table('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions');
        });
```

Questions:

```
Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id()->primary();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->text('title');
            $table->text('name');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
```

This is literally in the Laravel docs, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I was hoping someone could give me more insight in what's going wrong and how to fix it. Is it the order in which the migrations are executed?

Thanks in advance :)

I tried making my database tables with Laravel migrations.

I was expecting to create database tables by running the migration files.

I got the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `users` add primary key (id))

Comment: `id()` implies `primary()` so its presence is redundant. Also you are creating your foreign keys incorrectly. Documentation is quite clear that you should be using e.g. `$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();`. And why are you using two different closures in some of your migrations?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.  Also take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Hey i see you specifically add `primary()` with your id() in **user** migration.

Try to remove `primary` because `id()` is by default an alias for `bigIncrements`
and it creates an auto-incrementing `UNSIGNED BIGINT (primary key)` equivalent column.

For reference you can look in laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-method-bigIncrements)